# Using FFT to find time-dependence of quantum mechanical free particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, computational-physics, fourier-transform, software

I am trying to visualize the time dependence of a free particle given an initial wave-function using Python and I just wanted to know if I could use the in built FFT implementation from NumPy to find the coefficients of the integral

$$
\Psi(x,\,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(k)\exp\left[i\left(kx-\frac{\hbar k^2}{2m}t\right)\right]\,\mathrm{d}k
$$

Logically, it seems like doing a discrete Fourier transform to simulate a Fourier transform on an array of values representing $f(x)$ is okay, but I'm wondering if there are some subtleties I might be missing that actually changes the physical interpretation of my results when using a discrete Fourier transform to find $\phi(k)$ instead of a continuous one.

Comment: You may get a better answer on [Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)